# run a shell script in linux to process multiple .grb files

Tags: command-line, bash

I have the following shell script (myscript.sh) for processing of multiple .grb files to convert to .nc (netCDF) format. I have placed this in the same folder where the .grb files are located and ran "myscript.sh" like below.

List of .grb files in the "Binary" folder are like below:

```
NLDAS_VIC0125_H.A19901231.0000.002.grb
NLDAS_VIC0125_H.A19901231.0100.002.grb
.
.
NLDAS_VIC0125_H.A19901231.0500.002.grb 

~Downloads/Binary$ bash myscript.sh

#!/bin/bash
for i in 000 100 200 300 400 500
cdo -f nc copy NLDAS_VIC0125_H.A19901231.0{i}.002.grb NLDAS_VIC0125_H.A19901231.0{i}.002.nc
done
```

My script gives me an error:

```
script.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `cdo'
script.sh: line 3: `cdo -f nc copy NLDAS_VIC0125_H.A19901231.0{i}.002.grb NLDAS_VIC0125_H.A19901231.0{i}.002.nc'
```

Can somebody help me to correct this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: At the end of the command is a ' instead of a `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is missing a `do` and your variables are missing their de-referencing `$`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 000 100 200 300 400 500
do
  cdo -f nc copy NLDAS_VIC0125_H.A19901231.0${i}.002.grb NLDAS_VIC0125_H.A19901231.0${i}.002.nc
done
```

However if you want to loop over *all* the `.grb` files in the directory it would be simpler to use a `*` wildcard, and derive the `nc` filename from the `.grb` one by removing and replacing its extension

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.grb
do
  cdo -f nc copy "$file" "${file%.grb}.nc"
done
```

Also, it's better practice to make the script executable and simply call it by name

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
```

then

```
./myscript.sh
```